# Put + sign in front of positive numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, number-formatting

I like to display a plus sign before positive numbers. Example

```
2.to_s
# returns +2
```

and

```
-2.to_s
# returns -2
```

Comment: Do you want to do this automatically when any positive number is stringified?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: Do you want `+0` or `0`? (given that zero isn't positive)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) with a `+` flag:

```
sprintf('%d', 11)
# 11
sprintf('%+d', 11)
# +11
```

or equivalently, [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25):

```
'%+d<x>' % { x: 23 }
# +23
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fairly straight-up monkey patch to `Numeric`:

```
class Numeric
  def to_ss   # to signed string
    self.negative? ? self.to_s : "+#{self.to_s}"
  end
end

2.to_ss   # => "+2"
-2.to_ss  # => "-2"
5.7.to_ss # => "+5.7"
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there are more elegant ways, but this works.

Comment: Instead of a monkey patch, use a [refinement](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html). It's a scoped monkey patch.